# Drawing on Existing Images in android

Tags: android, image, drawing

I am trying to create an android application same as finger paint on the canvas, the only change my app has is the canvas contain a mutable image upon it, so it seems to be paint over that image. My problem is that when i draw any of the color over the image(canvas) its overlaps the image and user can't judge the portion that was painted over. Is there any solution by which i can paint the image as we apint an image with water color(i.e., with some transparencies) I want to see the image portion that was I just painted.

I had already saw this kind off application in iPhone, so hope it may also be possible in android too...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey All, I did it...
It is possible with the help of PorterDuffXfermode and Xfermode in android. I also used an extra layer, here, for saving the image...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Paint.setAlpha()` is what you're looking for. Use a Paint with alpha in the canvas draw-Methods.

Comment: Thanks Devisnik for ur reply, I had tried this one earlier but unfortunately it reduces the color quality(or reduces its opacity).I can use this one too but the major problem with this is that when i again and again use this color on same portion the result is more horrible...

Comment: So you want transparency only on the image you draw on, right, not on the parts that are drawn on top of it. I think you need an extra layer for that. You could draw into an offscreen bitmap and then draw that with a given alpha on top of the image.

Comment: Thanks Devisnik for ur quick attention... I found the solution as given below